# nosetests running tests for specific class in multi class python file -m doesnt work!!!! arggh

Tags: nosetests

I've been at this problem for a day now. :( Can't figure it out. Help please.
I have this setup:

class Parent(object):
    pass # common stuff goes here

class A(Parent, unittest.TestCase):
    pass # A stuff here

class B(Parent, unittest.TestCase):
    pass # B stuff here

I want to use nosetests to run only the tests on class B and parent since B inherits from parent. I thought I'd use -m or --match to put the class name but it doesnt seem to work.

Default matching is using --match is '(?:^|[\b_./-])[Tt]est'

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

First, check out [Nose's documentation about test selection](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#selecting-tests).  It's much easier than what you are trying to do!  If all the test classes `A` and `B` are in a file called `mytests.py`, this command would run only the tests for class `A`:

```
nosetests mytests.py:A
```

You can further limit execution to a single method of class `A`:

```
nosetests mytests.py:A.testOne
```

These can be combined.  To run all test methods for `A` and only the `testTwo` method of `B`, try this:

```
nosetests mytests.py:A mytests.py:B.testTwo
```